# Sub query for column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing something like below at the moment

```
Select T1.Col1,T1.Col2, (Select top 1 Id
                   From Table2
                   Where Ref=T1.Id
                   Order By Date Desc) AS T2Id,

                     (Select top 1 Title
                   From Table2
                   Where Ref=T1.Id
                   Order By Date Desc) AS T2Title
From Table1 T1
```

Is there any easy way I can retrieve both at once without querying same table twise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use  [cross apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) here

```
Select T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T2.Id,T2.Title
From Table1 T1
    cross apply  (Select top 1 Id, Title
                   From Table2
                   Where Ref=T1.Id
                   Order By Date Desc) AS T2
```